# How to get value width from input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this example i want to show an alert when input value width or cursor cross the input width. How to get value width from input field but not value length using jQuery?

```js
$('.value_width').text($('.input').val().length); //this is just length of value but not value width
$('.input_width').text($('.input').width());

$('.input').keyup(function(){
    $('.value_width').text($(this).val().length); //this is just length of value but not value width
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" name="" value="Example Text" />
<p/>
Value width : <span class="value_width"></span>
<br/>
Input width : <span class="input_width"></span>
```

Comment: add maxlength attribute

Comment: `value length width` ?, I don't understand....

Comment: I don't want that.

Comment: `value length width` means `input value width` not `input width` .

Answer (score 2):

You can check like this

```js
$('.value_width').text($('.input').val().length);
$('.input_width').text($('.input').width());

$('.input').keyup(function(){
    $('.value_width').text($(this).val().length);
     if(22<=$(this).val().length){
      alert('length filled');
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" name="" value="Example Text" />
<p/>
Value width : <span class="value_width"></span>
<br/>
Input width : <span class="input_width"></span>
```

Comment: I've found hard to understand what the user needs, I think you understood him, but if the OP wants that, then that is very weird in my opinion. What does the number of pixels have to do with the character length in input, I can't understand

Comment: @Hiptop you input filed width will not change by inserting value it will remain same.The question is that what you want ?Do you want to alert when the visible input field is fill up ?

Comment: Do you want to alert when the visible input field is fill up ?

Comment: You can do this by calculating string length like i am taking `22` ,just try ti again.